# Condicional para mudança de Activity

Tags: java, android, app, android-activity, sharedpreferences

Ola, estou com um problema, quero criar uma condicional em uma activity, dentro de um botão, para abrir uma outra activity no meu app.

> Mas como seria essa condicional?

o meu app tem botões na main activity que leva a outras activityies. Uma dessas activityies é um cadastro, onde o usuário preenche uns dados em alguns Editexts e os salva, eu usei o SharedPreferences para Salvar esses dados.

```
//Exemplo
SharedPreferences anonacpref = getSharedPreferences("anonac", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor edanonac = anonacpref.edit();
edanonac.putString("anonac_texto", anonactxt.getText().toString());
edanonac.commit();
```

Enfim, eu gostaria de que quando os dados já estivessem salvos, quando o usuario apertasse o botão na main activity ele fosse levado para outra activity ao em vez de ser levado para a activity de preenchimento do banco de dados.

> como faço pra testar se já tem algo salvo na                     SharedPreferences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SharedPreferences anonacpref = getSharedPreferences("anonac", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String texto = anonacpref.getString("anonac_texto", null);
if (texto != null) {
    System.out.println("Já preenchido com: " + texto);
} else {
    System.out.println("Texto não encontrado em shared preferences.");
}
```

O segundo parâmetro do `getString()` é o valor default, a ser retornado caso não encontre o valor de `"anonac_texto"` no arquivo de shared preferences. No caso estou usando `null`.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Piovezan. Eu entendi que no código que você postou, você está salvando o valor salvo no shared preferences em uma variável do tipo string, mas se os dados foram salvos, usando a shared preferences, em uma Activity e depois armazenados na variável nessa mesma activity, eu posso usar essa variável como parâmetro em outra activity? Se sim, como eu faço isso?

Comment: Não. Você busca de shared preferences em uma Activity, e em outra Activity busca de shared preferences de novo. Se quer evitar duplicidade de código, crie uma classe que leia campos específicos de shared preferences.

Comment: Poderia me dar um exemplo de código?

Comment: Veja a classe SharedPreference (sem s no final) [desse tutorial](http://androidopentutorials.com/android-sharedpreferences-tutorial-and-example/) e ela sendo usada nas classes MainActivity e SecondActivity.